# Test Spring-Rest Service with embedded Jetty

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jetty

i want to create an embedded jetty server (not maven, gradle etc.) to test a spring rest service.

Therefor i created an EmbeddedServer class. But unfortunately invocation of the rest service leads always to an http 404 error. What doing wrong?

The rest service works fine with tomcat (not embedded).

Im using the following dependencies:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:8.1.17.v20150415"
"org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:8.1.17.v20150415"
```

Here is the EmbededServer class:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class EmbeddedServer {

    private Server server;

    public void start() throws Exception {
        this.server = createServer();
        this.server.start();
    }

    public void stop() throws Exception {
        this.server.stop();
        this.server.join();
        this.server.destroy();
    }

    private Server createServer() {
        final Server server = new Server(8080);

        final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
        context.setDescriptor("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        context.setServer(server);

        server.setHandler(context);

        return server;
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class SimpleTest {

    private HttpClient client;
    private EmbeddedServer server;

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        this.client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        this.server = new EmbeddedServer();
        this.server.start();
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws Exception {
        this.server.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void invokeHello() throws Exception {
        final HttpResponse response = invokeGetRequest("http://localhost:8080/hello");
        verifyResponse(response, 200, "hello");
    }

    private HttpResponse invokeGetRequest(final String path) throws Exception {
        final URI wsAddress = new URI(path);
        final HttpGet method = new HttpGet(wsAddress);
        return this.client.execute(method);
    }

    private void verifyResponse(final HttpResponse actualHttpResponse, final int expectedHttpCode, final String expectedResponse) throws IOException {
        assertThat(actualHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(expectedHttpCode));

        final String actualResponse = EntityUtils.toString(actualHttpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        assertThat(actualResponse, equalTo(expectedResponse));
    }
}
```

This test fails with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expected: <200>
  but: was <404>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Path of ResourceBase and Descriptor must be absolute.

```
context.setResourceBase("c:/myapp/src/main/webapp");
context.setDescriptor("c:/myapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
```