# @Autowire objects in JUnit tests, how to load them?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, junit, dependency-injection

I have a Spring 4 project which I am creating a JUnit test for a specific Controller. Inside my JUnit test I have the current code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseConfiguration.class, ServiceConfiguration.class, ProcessFileController.class})
public class ProcessFileControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void getPageTest() throws Exception{
        final ProcessFileController controller = new ProcessFileController();
        SecurityHelperUtility.setupSecurityContext("user", "pass", "ROLE_ADMIN");
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();

        mockMvc.perform(get(URI.create("/processFile.html")).sessionAttr("freeTrialEmailAddress", "")).andExpect(view().name("processFile"));
    }

}
```

Wich I Load my Database, Service and actual Controller with this piece of code:

`@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DatabaseConfiguration.class, ServiceConfiguration.class, ProcessFileController.class})`

The problem is that I always get this stack trace when I run a JUnit test:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'processFileController': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CompanyService
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.controller.ProcessFileController.companyService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'companyService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryService
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CompanyServiceBasic.countryService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'countryService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.util.Properties
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryServiceBasic.fatcaWebProperties;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=FatcaWeb)}  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CompanyService
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.controller.ProcessFileController.companyService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'companyService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryService
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CompanyServiceBasic.countryService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'countryService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.util.Properties
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryServiceBasic.fatcaWebProperties;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=FatcaWeb)}  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     ... 41 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'companyService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryService
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CompanyServiceBasic.countryService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'countryService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.util.Properties
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryServiceBasic.fatcaWebProperties;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=FatcaWeb)}  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>     ... 43 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryService
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CompanyServiceBasic.countryService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'countryService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.util.Properties
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryServiceBasic.fatcaWebProperties;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=FatcaWeb)}  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     ... 54 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'countryService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.util.Properties
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryServiceBasic.fatcaWebProperties;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=FatcaWeb)}  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>     ... 56 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private java.util.Properties
>   com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryServiceBasic.fatcaWebProperties;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=FatcaWeb)}  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     ... 67 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @javax.inject.Named(value=FatcaWeb)}  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>     ... 69 more

What I can see is that is falling to load some Injections. Any clue to solve this?

Thanks.

As asked in the comments, my classes are above:

DataBaseConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource dataSource = new org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxTotal(50);
        dataSource.setLogAbandoned(true);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(2);
        dataSource.setMaxConnLifetimeMillis(2 * 60 * 1000 ); //Milliseconds (2 minutes)
        dataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        return localSessionFactoryBean;

    }


    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);    
        return transactionManager;
    }   

    @Bean
    public CountryDAOHibernate countryDAO() {
        return new CountryDAOHibernate();
    }

    @Bean
    public CompanyDAOHibernate companyDAO() {
        return new CompanyDAOHibernate();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDAOHibernate userDAO() {
        return new UserDAOHibernate();
    }

    @Bean
    public LicenseDAOHibernate licenseDAO() {

        return new LicenseDAOHibernate();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntermediateCertificateDAOHibernate intermediateCertificateDAO() {

        return new IntermediateCertificateDAOHibernate();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorityDAOHibernate authorityDAO() {

        return new AuthorityDAOHibernate();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserCompanyDAOHibernate userCompanyDAO() {

        return new UserCompanyDAOHibernate();
    }   
}
```

ServiceConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CountryService countryService() {
        return new CountryServiceBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    CompanyService companyService() {
        return new CompanyServiceBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    UserService userService() {
        return new UserServiceBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    LicenseService licenseService() {
        return new LicenseServiceBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    IntermediateCertificateService intermediateCertificateService(){
        return new IntermediateCertificateServiceBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthorityService authorityService(){
        return new AuthorityServiceBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    EmailSenderService emailSenderService(){
        return new EmailSenderBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: show your classes and config

Comment: @Dmitry, I just edited and inserted the Config Classes, the Controller is a normal Spring Controller with Autowire and Autowired Properties Files with the Name tag.

Comment: The key problem is here: `Could not autowire field: private java.util.Properties com.opessoftware.fatca.web.service.CountryServiceBasic.fatcaWebProperties`. You should fix (or show at least) `fatcaWebProperties` field of `CountryServiceBasic` class.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, I undertood, but how I can Autowire a properties file in my JUnit test? Any idea?

Comment: You can use a jetty server to instantiate your spring context.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529368/test-spring-rest-service-with-embedded-jetty

Comment: Typically you don't autowire `Properties` objects directly. You can have Spring bind the properties for you (with `@Value` or `@ConnfigurationProperties`), or inject an `Environment` or other `PropertyResolver` object.